# How to establish a click listener in a separate class from the event Vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, leaflet, vaadin, vaadin7

I am very new to Vaadin and v-Leaflet.  I have created a component that takes some geojson data and puts it over a map.  I am able to click on any of the polygons/ multi polygons and get back a few bits of information in the form of a notification.  The thing is, I need to take this information and click event and have it influence about 4 other separate components in their own separate classes.  I have been racking my brain with this for the past 2 days and just can't seem to grasp it.

Here is my map/ click event:

```
private LMap map;
        String filePath = this.getClass().getResource("/fccpeasgeo.json").getPath();
        File file = new File(filePath);
        //ArrayList<String> peaNames = new ArrayList<String>();



        //@Override
        public LMap createMap() {

            map = new LMap();

             FeatureJSON io = new FeatureJSON();
                try {
                    long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    // Look ma, no proxy needed, how cool is that!
                    FeatureCollection fc = io.readFeatureCollection(file);
                    Logger.getLogger(LeafletMap.class.getName()).severe("Download in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTimeMillis));
                    currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    FeatureIterator iterator = fc.features();
                    try {
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            Feature feature = iterator.next();
                            final String name = feature.getProperty("PEA_Name").getValue().toString();
                            final String population = feature.getProperty("POPs_2010").getValue().toString();
                            Geometry geometry = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometryProperty().getValue();

                            // The geojson provided in example is rather complex (several megabytes)
                            // Use JTS to simplyfy. Note that it is rather easy to use 
                            // different settings on different zoom levels, as well as decide
                            // to drop the feature form client altogether
                            geometry = DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.simplify(geometry, 0.2);

                            // In this example can be Polygon/Multipolygon
                            Collection<LeafletLayer> toLayers = JTSUtil.toLayers(geometry);
                            for (LeafletLayer l : toLayers) {
                                map.addComponent(l);
                                if (l instanceof LPolygon) {
                                    LPolygon lPolygon = (LPolygon) l;
                                    lPolygon.addClickListener(new LeafletClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(LeafletClickEvent event) {
                                            Notification.show("PEA: " + name + " Population: " + population);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Logger.getLogger(LeafletMap.class.getName()).severe("Reducing and creating layers " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTimeMillis));

                    } finally {
                        iterator.close();
                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LeafletMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LeafletMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            map.zoomToContent();
            //map.setCenter(40, -95.2);
            //map.setZoomLevel(2.5);
            LTileLayer tf = new LTileLayer();
            tf.setUrl("http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png");
            tf.setSubDomains(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
            tf.setActive(true);
            map.addBaseLayer(tf, "ThunderForest Transport");

            return map;

        }
```

Here is one of the components that will be receiving the event.

```
public Chart mhzPerSqMile() {
        Chart chart = new Chart();


        run();

        chart.setCaption("Total MHz Per Square Mile");
        chart.getConfiguration().setTitle("");
        chart.getConfiguration().getChart().setType(ChartType.PIE);
        chart.getConfiguration().getChart().setAnimation(false);
        chart.setWidth("100%");
        chart.setHeight("90%");

        DataSeries series = new DataSeries();

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName()!=null)
            {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("abcTask"))
                {

                }
             }


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Operator operator = operators.get(i);
            if (selectedPea != null) {
                if (operator.getPeaName().toLowerCase() == selectedPea.toLowerCase()){
                    DataSeriesItem item = new DataSeriesItem(operator.getName(),
                    operator.getTotalMHzSqMile());
            series.add(item);
            item.setColor(DummyDataGenerator.chartColors[i]);
        }
            }
            }
        chart.getConfiguration().setSeries(series);
        PlotOptionsPie opts = new PlotOptionsPie();
        opts.setBorderWidth(0);
        opts.setShadow(false);
        opts.setAnimation(false);
        chart.getConfiguration().setPlotOptions(opts);

        Credits c = new Credits("");
        chart.getConfiguration().setCredits(c);


        return chart;
    }
    }
}
```

Any advice would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

what I think you simply need to fire a property with any specific name (Event name) and all your listener classes have implemented `PropertyChangeListener` which triggers on every `fireProperty()`  call , obviously you are matching your event name there and hence all you 4 classes perform their task upon receiving such a property change

You need to register `PropertyChangeSupport` for current instance

```
PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
```

further you'll use this object to fire your event

Firing event

```
//this firing code will probably go inside your click method that actually causes an event to occur
    pcs.firePropertyChange("abcTask", oldValue, newValue);
```

Recieving event

```
@Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) 
    {
        if (evt.getPropertyName()!=null)
        {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("abcTask"))
            {
                //perform task
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this seems to make a lot of sense!  Do you think we could chat for a minute about more specifics about implementing this into the program?  I'm new to Vaadin and am just getting confused about a few steps.  @SSH

Comment: i am glad if it helps you, also accept this answer if it works for you...also you can ask if you have any further queries i'll try my best to answer you

Comment: I guess my first point of confusion is about what oldValue and newValue should be if the thing I need changed as a result of the event is a String.  For example, when the event fires, I need the components to get the new "name" from the clicked on part of the map and use it in its logic.  I added one of the component classes to the code for context. @SSH

Comment: oldValue and newValue are the two object type arguments it expects so that you can pass any object through that event call, and also you can pass null to any of them or both depending on your needs

Comment: like i have a textfield and upon changing its value i need to fire event with the oldvalue that was in the textfield previously and also the new value which is present now, so i can pass them , or if i have nothing previously i can pass null...all my logic plays the further

Comment: so in your case you can put the name of the place which you got from map as a newValue and oldValue as null....making it clear once again its not a universal rule...you can also pass either way...and you must have a right logic at receiving end

Comment: Okay this is starting to really make sense to me now.  I think the last part I am stuck on is where I put the logic for displaying the correct data series for the chart and how I access the newValue that is being passed to it.  Because I have a separate array list of "operators" and the way I decide what to add to the data series is by checking the operators names against the name received from the map so how do I access that value and put it into the necessary conditional? @SSH

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91398/discussion-between-ssh-and-nick-emmons).